# Show/hide Afterpay message on Shopify product page

Tags: shopify

On the Shopify Product page we have two purchase options (radio buttons): one-time and subscription.
We don't want to offer Afterpay for subscribers, but I struggle to find how to hide that message because that widget is initiated on page load and I can't change it later (or even attach any className to it to manipulate later). If anybody has solved how to do that, please share the work-around.

Comment: I think you need to check the javascript to hide and show the widget once someone switches to the subscription radio box over the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I created an empty div with child div inside and attached Afterpay widget to it. Now I can manipulate a whole div and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making the font-size of text to zero. Added below CSS.

```
afterpay-placement { 
  --messaging-font-size: 0px; 
}
```